# Gtk's XInput2 detection test doesn't work

Tags: configure, xorg, pkg-config, xinput

I am currently executing the configure script of gtk. It tests for the presence of XInput, and it stops the execution with the error message:

> "configure: error: *** XInput2 extension not found. Check 'config.log' for more details."

Looking at config.log, it says

> "configure:23050: error: *** XInput2 extension not found. Check 'config.log' for more details."

So, the same except for the line number.

Then I decided to look at configure.ac. There I found the full Xi detection test that it is:

```
if $PKG_CONFIG --exists "xi" ; then

X_PACKAGES="$X_PACKAGES xi"
GTK_PACKAGES_FOR_X="$GTK_PACKAGES_FOR_X xi"

AC_CHECK_HEADER(X11/extensions/XInput2.h,
                have_xinput2=yes
                AC_DEFINE(XINPUT_2, 1, [Define to 1 if XInput 2.0 is available]))

gtk_save_LIBS="$LIBS"
LIBS="$LIBS -lXi"

# Note that we also check that the XIScrollClassInfo struct is defined,
# because at least Ubuntu Oneiric seems to have XIAllowTouchEvents(), but not the XIScrollClassInfo struct.
AC_CHECK_FUNC([XIAllowTouchEvents],
  [AC_CHECK_MEMBER([XIScrollClassInfo.number],
                   have_xinput2_2=yes
                   AC_DEFINE(XINPUT_2_2, 1, [Define to 1 if XInput 2.2 is available]),
                   have_xinput2_2=no,
                   [[#include <X11/extensions/XInput2.h>]])])
LIBS="$gtk_save_LIBS"

if test "x$have_xinput2_2" = "xyes"; then
  X_EXTENSIONS="$X_EXTENSIONS XI2.2"
else
  X_EXTENSIONS="$X_EXTENSIONS XI2"
 fi
fi

AS_IF([test "x$have_xinput2" != "xyes"],
    [AC_MSG_ERROR([*** XInput2 extension not found. Check 'config.log' for more details.])])
```

I am no expert about setting configure.ac, but I thought that the line:

> "if $PKG_CONFIG --exists "xi" ; then"

would be satisfied by this parameter that I pass to configure:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=:/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/xorg/Xi-1.5.0/lib/pkgconfig/
```

Also this line:

```
AC_CHECK_HEADER(X11/extensions/XInput2.h,
                have_xinput2=yes
                AC_DEFINE(XINPUT_2, 1, [Define to 1 if XInput 2.0 is available]))
```

could not have been satisfied by this parameter that I pass to configure:

1. List item

> CPPFLAGS=-I/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/xorg/Xi-1.5.0/include/

I am a bit lost about why it doesn't detect nothing.

A curious point that I read in the documentation is that there is a parameter called: --disable-xinput.
Well I am passing it to configure and it obviously didn't disable the test. So I would appreciate any suggestions about how to change the test to try to figure out what is wrong with it (or with my system)